# The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services'

Tags: ios, icloud, ios9, cloudkit

I'm using a public iCloud database in my app, which works great and is up on the store.

On updating my app to a new version (with Xcode 7 on iOS9) I get a crash on the line :

```
CKContainer * container = [CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"iCloud.com.identifier"];

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services'
```

This happens ONLY the first launch of the app after updating, and only on iOS9.  After that first (update) launch, the app launches and iCloud works as expected.

I can recreate the crash consistently by downloading the current store version of the app, then running the updated app from Xcode 7.

If I do the same steps (download production app, and update) using iOS8, I do not have the same crash.

I'm guessing this is an iOS9 or Xcode 7 bug.  Any ideas?

EDIT :
This actually happens on the first launch of the app on iOS9, regardless of whether I'm updating or just first installing.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. None of the answers worked for me. I only see these crashes on Fabric/Crashlytics/Firebase and not in Xcode organizer. A lot of the crashes are coming from jailbroken devices but not all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Toggling the iCloud Capability on and off seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

**Xcode 11.1**

Make sure you have enabled it for both **debug** and **release** mode:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Toggling iCloud didn't work for me. Reinstalling the app didn't work either. The problem seems to happen whenever I have break points enabled. If I turn these off it runs without any problem.

Comment: oh btw: I only had the issue on 64bit devices, but who knows if that's actually related

Comment: i didn't have any break points, but it still didn't work. (`iPhone 5s, iOS 9.2`)

Comment: No break points for me, either. Still not working with a macOS 10.13.5 app. :(

Comment: It can also be a jailbreak issue for production build. You can enclose the call in @try-catch block to avoid crash and then handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had Code Signing Entitlements designated for my Test target. So the app would build fine. But the unit tests would just quit no matter what. Clearing out the Code Signing Entitlements field from the Build Settings of the test target fixed the issue. After. Many. Hours.

Answer (score 1):

For me toggling the iCloud capability off/on was the way to fix it, due to after that in the entitlements file a new key is created: "APS Environment" and its value "production" or "deployment".

Answer (score 0):

Changed the name of my app, therefore the entitlements file should have been different. Turning off and back on recreated the required file. Turning off breakpoints made it filter through (strange).

Answer (score 0):

After switching to a new version of Xcode I got this error. None of the other fixes worked. After looking closely I saw that the code signing identity had changed! When I put it back all worked.