# "Network Failure" (4/NSURLErrorDomain:-1202); "The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: ios, xamarin, exception, xamarin.ios, icloud

I have configured the iCloud storage in my Xamarin.iOS app, it works properly on simulator but, on physical device, it throws the following exception when accessing the database using the following code.

`CKContainer.DefaultContainer.PrivateCloudDatabase;`

> Objective-C exception thrown. Name: CKException Reason: The
>   application is missing required entitlement
>   com.apple.developer.icloud-services Native stack trace: 0
>   CoreFoundation 0x00000001a921ead0

I have tried the following changes before posting here.

1. Set different HTTPClient implementation from project options.
2. Set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true from info.plist.
3. Tried both debug and release builds.
4. Tried with both development and distribution profile.
5. Reset the device and enable/disable automatic date time.

Comment: Have you enabled the iCloud in Entitlements.plist/Apple dev console?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled in both Entitlements.plist and provisioning profile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728300/the-application-is-missing-required-entitlement-com-apple-developer-icloud-servi)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have already red all the answers from that link, and nothing helped me.